# Disable the option to add an object that is already in an array that was loaded from NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm loading recipes from a plist to NSArray (of custom objects Recipe) and display them in a UITableView.
I added an option in the detail view to add recipes to favorites view.

Obviously I want the option to save the user's favorites selection so I conformed my custom class to NSCoding and added the initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder methods to my custom object.

After I relaunch the app, the favorites array is saved and reloaded correctly.
The problem is that I can add the same recipe every relaunch (While the app is running I can add and remove the recipe just fine).

Can someone help me think of a way to disable the option to add a recipe that was already added the previous time the app was running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check an array with the `[array containsObject:obj]` method, it will also require to have proper `isEqual:` method implemented in your class.

Also, you might consider using `NSSet` instead of `NSArray`, since `NSSet` better logically fits unique set of objects than `NSArray`. With NSSet you will still need to have the `isEqual:` implemented!

Comment: @Gobra Doesn't using NSSet means the elements are unordered? What if I want the user to be able to reorder the collection? What if the order does matter?

Comment: it depends on reorder type. if user can explicitly move item up & down - stick with NSArray, if it just a kind of sorting, it's easier to keep sort descriptions and apply the sorting in controller, I think.

Comment: Thanks, so I'll stick with NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

you can make them override -hash and -isEqual: and use a set... then you can try to add them over and over, and it wont matter, because a set only holds one of each... or you can keep using an array and check the array for the object.

```
if ([someArray indexOfObject:someObj]==NSNotFound)
{
    [someArray addObject:someObj];
}
```